# Can you use templates to nest an enum class inside a containing class

Tags: c++, enums

I an trying to describe a sensor CFA in a class or struct.  Id like to be able to do something like this:

```
enum class cfa_type
{
  RGGB,
  RCCB
};

enum class RGGB_ch
{
  R,
  G1,
  G2,
  B
};
enum class RCCB_ch
{
  R,
  C1,
  C2,
  B
};

template <typename CH>
struct CFA
{
  cfa_type type;
  CH ch;
  CFA(cfa_type t) : type(t) {}
};
```

eventually, what I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
CFA<RGGB_ch> RGGB(cfa_type::RGGB);
std::cout << static_cast<int>(RGGB.ch::R);
```

but right now, I get compiler errors:

```
 error: ‘ch’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
   52 |  std::cout << static_cast<int>(RGGB.ch::R);
      |                                  ^
```

which makes sense, but I am wondering is there a way to do this or something like this so I don't need to write a bunch of combinations and use enum classes instead of just numbers for the channels?

Comment: `CFA<RGGB_ch> RGGB(cfa_type::RGGB);` doesn't compile, since `CFA` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `cfa_type` value as input. Besides, it would be redundant to pass in a `cfa_type` value anyway since `CFA` could just use a little template magic to automatically deduce an appropriate `cfa_type` value based on the type passed to its `CH` template argument.

Comment: That was a cut / paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type is not a variable.

```
static_cast<int>(decltype(RGGB.ch)::R);
```

Comment: Or, if you want to expose the enum as a member type, `using ch = CH;`

Comment: That is closer to what I want.  I am beginning to think I am better off with a class that holds a map or something along those lines....